# Kruskal's Maze Algorithm - Only Working up to dimension 11x11

Tags: c#, maze, kruskals-algorithm

I am using https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/07su/prj2/kruskal.html psuedocode as reference when writing my code.

Code is in C#, and my code can only generate mazes up to 11x11, anything more than than it will run, seemingly, forever (e.g. 12x11 or 12x12 won't work)

Grid Properties are just storing the dimension of the size of the maze

```
    public class GridProperties
    {
        private int xLength;
        private int yLength;
        public GridProperties(int xlength, int ylength)
        {
            xLength = xlength;
            yLength = ylength;
        }

        public int getXLength()
        {
            return this.xLength;
        }
        public int getYLength()
        {
            return this.yLength;
        }
    }
```

Cell Properties generates the grid

```
    public class CellProperties
    {
        private GridProperties Grid;
        private bool topWall, bottomWall, rightWall, leftWall;
        private int? xCoord, yCoord;
        private CellProperties topCell, bottomCell, rightCell, leftCell;
        private CellProperties topParentCell, bottomParentCell, rightParentCell, leftParentCell;
        private HashSet<String> passageID = new HashSet<String>();
        public CellProperties(GridProperties grid = null, int? targetXCoord = null, int? targetYCoord = null,
            CellProperties tpCell = null, CellProperties bpCell = null, 
            CellProperties rpCell = null, CellProperties lpCell = null)
        {
            this.Grid = grid;

            this.xCoord = targetXCoord;
            this.yCoord = targetYCoord;

            this.updatePassageID(this.xCoord.ToString() + this.yCoord.ToString());

            this.topWall = true;
            this.bottomWall = true;
            this.rightWall = true;
            this.leftWall = true;

            this.topParentCell = tpCell;
            this.bottomParentCell = bpCell;
            this.rightParentCell = rpCell;
            this.leftParentCell = lpCell;

            this.topCell = this.setTopCell();
            this.bottomCell = this.setBottomCell();
            if (this.yCoord == 0)
            {
                this.rightCell = this.setRightCell();
            }
            this.leftCell = this.setLeftCell();
        }

        public CellProperties setTopCell()
        {
            if (this.Grid == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (this.yCoord == this.Grid.getYLength() - 1)
            {
                return new CellProperties();
            }
            else
            {
                return new CellProperties(this.Grid, this.xCoord, this.yCoord + 1, null, this, null, null);
            }
        }
        public CellProperties setBottomCell()
        {
            if (this.yCoord == 0)
            {
                return new CellProperties();
            }
            else
            {
                return this.bottomParentCell;
            }
        }
        public CellProperties setRightCell()
        {
            if (this.Grid == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (this.xCoord == this.Grid.getXLength() - 1)
            {
                return new CellProperties();
            }
            else
            {
                return new CellProperties(this.Grid, this.xCoord + 1, this.yCoord, null, null, null, this);
            }
        }
        public CellProperties setLeftCell( )
        {
            if (this.xCoord == 0)
            {
                return new CellProperties();
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.Grid == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (this.yCoord == 0)
                {
                    return this.leftParentCell;
                }
                else
                {
                    CellProperties buffer = this.bottomCell;
                    for (int depth = 0; depth < this.yCoord - 1; depth++)
                    {
                        buffer = buffer.bottomParentCell;
                    }
                    buffer = buffer.leftParentCell.topCell;
                    for (int depth = 0; depth < this.yCoord - 1; depth++)
                    {
                        buffer = buffer.topCell;
                    }
                    buffer.rightCell = this;
                    return buffer;
                }
            }
        }

        public GridProperties getGrid()
        {
            return this.Grid;
        }
        public CellProperties getBottomCell()
        {
            return this.bottomCell;
        }
        public CellProperties getTopCell()
        {
            return this.topCell;
        }
        public CellProperties getLeftCell()
        {
            return this.leftCell;
        }
        public CellProperties getRightCell()
        {
            return this.rightCell;
        }

        public void setBottomWall(Boolean newBottomWall)
        {
            this.bottomWall = newBottomWall;
        }
        public void setTopWall(Boolean newTopWall)
        {
            this.topWall = newTopWall;
        }
        public void setLeftWall(Boolean newLeftWall)
        {
            this.leftWall = newLeftWall;
        }
        public void setRightWall(Boolean newRightWall)
        {
            this.rightWall = newRightWall;
        }
        public Boolean getBottomWall()
        {
            return this.bottomWall;
        }
        public Boolean getTopWall()
        {
            return this.topWall;
        }
        public Boolean getLeftWall()
        {
            return this.leftWall;
        }
        public Boolean getRightWall()
        {
            return this.rightWall;
        }

        public void updatePassageID(String newPassageID)
        { 
            this.passageID.Add(newPassageID);
        }
        public void setPassageID(HashSet<String> newPassageID)
        {
            this.passageID = new HashSet<string>(newPassageID);
        }
        public HashSet<String> getPassageID()
        {
            return this.passageID;
        }
    }
```

This class is where the magic happens ... or suppose to happen.

```
public class KruskalMazeGenerator
{
    private CellProperties Cell0x0;
    private CellProperties CurrentCell;
    private CellProperties NeighbourCell;
    private int WallsDown;
    private int TotalNumberOfCells;
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private int rndXCoord, rndYCoord;
    private String rndSide;
    public KruskalMazeGenerator(CellProperties cell0x0)
    {
        Cell0x0 = cell0x0;
        WallsDown = 0;
        TotalNumberOfCells = Cell0x0.getGrid().getXLength() * Cell0x0.getGrid().getYLength();
    }
    public void selectRandomCellCoords()
    {
        this.rndXCoord = rnd.Next(0, this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getXLength());
        this.rndYCoord = rnd.Next(0, this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getYLength());
    }
    public void selectRandomSide(String[] possibleSides)
    {
        if (possibleSides.Length != 0)
        {
            this.rndSide = possibleSides[rnd.Next(0, possibleSides.Length)];
        }
    }
    public void selectRandomCurrentCell()
    {
        this.selectRandomCellCoords();
        this.CurrentCell = this.Cell0x0;
        for (int xWalk = 0; xWalk < this.rndXCoord; xWalk++)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this.CurrentCell.getRightCell();
        }
        for (int xWalk = 0; xWalk < this.rndYCoord; xWalk++)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this.CurrentCell.getTopCell();
        }
    }
    public CellProperties checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(List<String> possibleSides)
    {
        if (this.rndSide == "top")
        {
            if (this.CurrentCell.getTopCell() == null || this.CurrentCell.getTopCell().getGrid() == null)
            {
                possibleSides.Remove("top");
                this.selectRandomSide(possibleSides.ToArray());
                return this.checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(possibleSides);
            }
            return this.CurrentCell.getTopCell();
        }
        else if (this.rndSide == "bottom")
        {
            if (this.CurrentCell.getBottomCell() == null || this.CurrentCell.getBottomCell().getGrid() == null)
            {
                possibleSides.Remove("bottom");
                this.selectRandomSide(possibleSides.ToArray());
                return this.checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(possibleSides);
            }
            return this.CurrentCell.getBottomCell();
        }
        else if (this.rndSide == "left")
        {
            if (this.CurrentCell.getLeftCell() == null || this.CurrentCell.getLeftCell().getGrid() == null)
            {
                possibleSides.Remove("left");
                this.selectRandomSide(possibleSides.ToArray());
                return this.checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(possibleSides);
            }
            return this.CurrentCell.getLeftCell();
        }
        else if (this.rndSide == "right")
        {
            if (this.CurrentCell.getRightCell() == null || this.CurrentCell.getRightCell().getGrid() == null)
            {
                possibleSides.Remove("right");
                this.selectRandomSide(possibleSides.ToArray());
                return this.checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(possibleSides);
            }
            return this.CurrentCell.getRightCell();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void selectRandomNeigbhourCell()
    {
        this.selectRandomSide(new String[4] { "top", "bottom", "left", "right" });
        this.NeighbourCell = this.checkWallBetweenCurrentAndNeighbour(new List<String>(new String[4] { "top", "bottom", "left", "right" }));
    }
    public void checkForDifferentPassageID()
    {
        if (!this.CurrentCell.getPassageID().SetEquals(this.NeighbourCell.getPassageID()))
        {
            if (this.rndSide == "top")
            {
                this.CurrentCell.setTopWall(false);
                this.NeighbourCell.setBottomWall(false);
                this.unionAndResetPassageID();
                this.WallsDown += 1;
            }
            else if (this.rndSide == "bottom")
            {
                this.CurrentCell.setBottomWall(false);
                this.NeighbourCell.setTopWall(false);
                this.unionAndResetPassageID();
                this.WallsDown += 1;
            }
            else if (this.rndSide == "left")
            {
                this.CurrentCell.setLeftWall(false);
                this.NeighbourCell.setRightWall(false);
                this.unionAndResetPassageID();
                this.WallsDown += 1;
            }
            else if (this.rndSide == "right")
            {
                this.CurrentCell.setRightWall(false);
                this.NeighbourCell.setLeftWall(false);
                this.unionAndResetPassageID();
                this.WallsDown += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    public void unionAndResetPassageID()
    {
        HashSet<String> oldCurrentPassageID = new HashSet<String>(this.CurrentCell.getPassageID());
        HashSet<String> oldNeighbourPassageID = new HashSet<String>(this.NeighbourCell.getPassageID());

        HashSet <String> newPassageID = new HashSet<String>();
        newPassageID = this.CurrentCell.getPassageID();
        newPassageID.UnionWith(this.NeighbourCell.getPassageID());

        CellProperties xwalkCell = new CellProperties();
        CellProperties ywalkCell = new CellProperties();
        for (int xWalk = 0; xWalk < this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getXLength(); xWalk++)
        {
            xwalkCell = xWalk == 0 ? this.Cell0x0 : xwalkCell.getRightCell();
            for (int yWalk = 0; yWalk < this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getYLength(); yWalk++)
            {
                xwalkCell.setBottomWall(xWalk == 0 && yWalk == 0 ? false : xwalkCell.getBottomWall());
                xwalkCell.setBottomWall(xWalk == this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getXLength() - 1 && yWalk == this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getYLength() - 1 ? false : xwalkCell.getBottomWall());
                ywalkCell = yWalk == 0 ? xwalkCell : ywalkCell.getTopCell();

                if (ywalkCell.getPassageID().SetEquals(oldCurrentPassageID) || 
                    ywalkCell.getPassageID().SetEquals(oldNeighbourPassageID))
                {
                    ywalkCell.setPassageID(newPassageID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public CellProperties createMaze()
    {
        while (this.WallsDown < this.TotalNumberOfCells - 1)
        {
            this.selectRandomCurrentCell();
            this.selectRandomNeigbhourCell();
            if (this.NeighbourCell != null)
            {
                this.checkForDifferentPassageID();
            }
        }
        return this.Cell0x0;
    }
}
```

then this is my visual representation class

```
    public class drawGrid : CellProperties
    {
        private CellProperties Cell0x0 = new CellProperties();
        private CellProperties yWalkBuffer = new CellProperties();
        private CellProperties xWalkBuffer = new CellProperties();
        private String bottomWall = "";
        private String topWall = "";
        private String leftAndrightWalls = "";

        public drawGrid(CellProperties cell0x0)
        {
            Cell0x0 = cell0x0;
        }

        private void WallDrawingReset()
        {
            this.bottomWall = "\n";
            this.topWall = "\n";
            this.leftAndrightWalls = "\n";
        }
        private void Draw()
        {
            // draw bottom wall
            {
                if (this.bottomWall == "\n")
                {
                    Console.Write("");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.Write(this.bottomWall);
                }
            }
            Console.Write(this.leftAndrightWalls);
            // draw top wall
            {
                if (topWall == "\n")
                {
                    Console.Write("");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.Write(this.topWall);
                }
            }
        }
        public void yWalk()
        {
            for (int yWalk = 0; yWalk < this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getYLength(); yWalk++)
            {
                this.yWalkBuffer = yWalk == 0 ? this.Cell0x0 : this.yWalkBuffer.getTopCell();

                this.WallDrawingReset();
                this.xWalk(yWalk);
                this.Draw();
            }
        }
        private void xWalk(int yWalk)
        {
            for (int xWalk = 0; xWalk < this.Cell0x0.getGrid().getXLength(); xWalk++)
            {
                this.xWalkBuffer = xWalk == 0 ? this.yWalkBuffer : this.xWalkBuffer.getRightCell();

                if (yWalk == 0)
                {
                    this.bottomWall = xWalkBuffer.getBottomWall() ? this.bottomWall + "----" : this.bottomWall + "    ";
                    this.topWall = xWalkBuffer.getTopWall() ? this.topWall + "----" : this.topWall + "    ";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.topWall = this.xWalkBuffer.getTopWall() ? this.topWall + "----" : this.topWall + "    ";
                }
                if (xWalk == 0)
                {
                    leftAndrightWalls = this.xWalkBuffer.getLeftWall() ? this.leftAndrightWalls + "|   " : this.leftAndrightWalls + "    ";
                    leftAndrightWalls = this.xWalkBuffer.getRightWall() ? this.leftAndrightWalls + "|   " : this.leftAndrightWalls + "    ";
                }
                else
                {
                    leftAndrightWalls = this.xWalkBuffer.getRightWall() ? this.leftAndrightWalls + "|   " : this.leftAndrightWalls + "    ";
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

this is how i call them

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                CellProperties cell = new CellProperties(new GridProperties(12, 11), 0, 0, null, null, null, null);
                drawGrid draw = new drawGrid(cell);
                draw.yWalk();
                KruskalMazeGenerator kmaze = new KruskalMazeGenerator(cell);
                cell = kmaze.createMaze();
                Console.WriteLine("Final");
                draw = new drawGrid(cell);
                draw.yWalk();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Since I got you guys here, please don't mind pitching in what I can improve on as in coding style and other things that you are displeased with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @coding style: you should consider droping the extensive use of ``this.`` and start fields in ``_`` to distinguish them between local variables, and since you use ``int`` and not ``Int32`` use ``string`` instead of ``String``

Comment: Also consider using actual properties instead of having explicit getter methods.  For the most part you've just written Java in C#.

Comment: Also you could use properties for all your getter/setter methods (aka `IsTopWall {get; set;}`. Would make it a lot more readable when you have `Cell.IsTopWall` instead of the setters and getters.

Comment: Thank you @Adwaenyth, did not know { get; set; } is a thing,  I will start using that shorthand from now on.

Comment: @Kyle  if you have time, please elaborate more, I am intrigued how you can tell I wrote Java in C# --- ( I did learn Java in school, and now I am trying to learn C# on my own)

Comment: @AlanHuang It was a guess based on the naming conventions you're following and the patterns you're using.  They're idiomatic in Java, but not in C#, so it's common to see C# written this way by people that learned Java.  For more information on properties specifically [see this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).  And here are [the naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

Comment: Another Code style: you should name your lists as plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error seems to be here:

```
this.updatePassageID(this.xCoord.ToString() + this.yCoord.ToString());
```

Image those two scenarios:

1. `xCoord` = `1` and `yCoord` = `11`.
2. `xCoord` = `11` and `yCoord` = `1`.

both those result in `newPassageID` of `111`.

So simply change the line to

```
this.updatePassageID(this.xCoord.ToString() + "|" + this.yCoord.ToString());
```

or written more sexy:

```
this.updatePassageID($"{xCoord}|{yCoord}");
```

With this you will receive 
`1|11` for the first scenario and `11|1` for the second which differs.

**Edit based on comments:**

I saw that your code is looping endlessly in the method `createMaze`. This method calls a method called `checkForDifferentPassageID` in there you check if two collections are equal or not. Once I saw that those collections are of type `HashSet<string>`, I thought that maybe your strings you put into the `HashSet` arent as unique as you think they are and there we go. So overall it took me like 10 minutes.

Comment: Actually, can you explain to me the process that lead you to the solution? So I can improve my skills - I worked on it for many hours and wasn't able to see this error. @RandRandom

Comment: Also, do you think hashing the coordinate information would be useful in this context?@RandRandom

Comment: @AlanHuang you mean to make it even more unique? Dont think thats necessary.